# LayoutAnimation is causing to many side effects, is there an alternative?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

We are trying to use `LayoutAnimation` to animate changes to our layout. For example, when an inline form error box pops up, we want the rest of the form to be pushed down smoothly.

The problem is when we use `LayoutAnimation` it is far too heavy handed in what it decides to animate. The problem being for us right now, it animates the `react-navigation` stack navigator in weird and undesirable ways.

I have been looking for an alternative way or a fix for this behavior. One solution I've been trying is to use `Animated` and `onLayout` to get around the problem, with some success. The problem that arises here is getting the layout to update when the children visually update.

So to make my questions clear: Has anyone else run into needing a less heavy handed version of LayoutAnimation? If so, how did you get around it?

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutAnimation` is a tool for executing simple animations and you almost have no control over it. There is another powerful tool for animations [`Animated`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html). It is flexible and you can control over them using life cycles methods. Check out [this book](http://browniefed.com/react-native-animation-book/API.html), it's a nice guide.

P.S. I hope this answer isn't too obvious for you. But `Animated` API is really cool thing for handling animations.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using `Animated` to work my way around this already. My original post explains what I've attempted with it and the problems I'm having in using it. I do believe it is the direction I need to go in, but the solution is complex because of requiring to know the heights of things before they're rendered.